# What's the difference between these two frame-dragging equation?

Tags: general-relativity, spacetime, frame-dragging

Conceptually, what is the difference between these two frame-dragging equations, describing the rate of angular velocity of the space around a symmetrically spherical mass such as a black hole and why would you use one over the other?

1: $\boldsymbol{\Omega} = \frac{r_s\alpha c}{r^3 + \alpha^2 (r + r_s)}$

where $\alpha$ is related to the angular momentum: $\alpha = \frac{J}{Mc}$

$r$ is the position vector above the rotating mass and $r_s$ is the Schwarzschild radius: $r_s = \frac{2GM}{c^2}$

2: $\boldsymbol{\Omega} = \frac{GI}{c^2r^3}\left( \frac{3(\boldsymbol{\omega}\cdot \boldsymbol{r})\boldsymbol{r}}{r^2}-\boldsymbol{\omega} \right)$

where $r$ is the position vector above the rotating mass, $I$ is the moment of inertia of the rotating mass, and $ω$ is the angular velocity of the rotating mass.

Comment: It is impossible to answer until you have provided further information. One needs to know what scenario you are describing, and what coordinates you are using, and what frames you are referring to. It could be a LIF in orbit around a spherical mass, or one falling radially towards to a rotating spherical mass, or a non-inertial frame held at a fixed location in some coordinate frame, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Your first equation is assuming the size and moment of inertia for a black hole (same as for a hollow shell) and is only valid in the equatorial plane (the full form depends also on θ), while the second one is for spheres with arbitrary size and moment of inertia in the weak field limit, so it's better suited to calculate the frame dragging around the earth.